# Breakdown of GKE bill based on pods or deployments

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-kubernetes-engine

I need a breakdown of my usage inside a single project categorized on the basis of Pods or Services or Deployments but the billing section in console doesn't seem to provide such granular information. Is it possible to get this data somehow? I want to know what was the network + compute cost on per deployment or pods. 
Or maybe if it is possible to have it atleast on the cluster level? Is this breakdown available in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently it was released a new features in GKE that allows to collect metrics inside a cluster that can also be combined with the exported billing data to separate costs per project/environment, making it possible to separate costs per namespace, deployment, labels, among other criteria.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/gke-usage-metering-whose-line-item-is-it-anyway

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible at the moment to breakdown the billing on a pod level, services or deployment, Kubernetes Engine uses Google Compute Engine instances for nodes in the cluster. You are billed for each of those instances according to [Compute Engine's pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing), until the nodes are deleted. Compute Engine resources are billed on a per-second basis with a 1 minute minimum usage cost.

You can [Export Billing Data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) enables you to export your daily usage and cost estimates automatically throughout the day to a BigQuery dataset you specify. You can then access your billing data from BigQuery then you can use [BigQuery queries on exported billing data](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples) to do some breakdown.

You can view your [usage reports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export) as well and estimate your kubernetes charges using the [GCP Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#tab=container). If you want to move forward you can create a [PIT request](https://issuetracker.google.com) as a future request

Comment: As of Dec 2018, there is also support for per-cluster & namespace-level billing granularity via the BigQuery resource export - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/clusters/create#--resource-usage-bigquery-dataset

Answer (score 1):

You can get this visibility with your GKE Usage Metering dataset and your BigQuery cost exports.

Cost per namespace, cost per deployment, per node can be obtained by writing queries to combine these tables. If you have labels set, you can drilldown based on labels too. It shows you what's the spend on CPU, RAM, and egress cost.

Check out [economize.cloud](https://www.economize.cloud/) - it integrates with your datasets and allows you to slice and dice views. For example, cost per customer or cost per service can be obtained with such granular cost data.

https://www.economize.cloud/blog/gke-usage-cost-monitoring-kubernetes-clusters/

Answer (score 1):

*New GCP offering:* GKE Cost Allocation allows users easily and natively view and manage the cost of a GKE cluster by cluster, namespace pod labels and more right from the Billing page or export Detailed usage cost data to Big Query:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cost-allocations

GKE Cost Allocation is a more accurate and robust compare to GKE Usage Metering.

Answer (score 0):

Kubecost provides Kubernetes cost allocation by any concept, e.g. pod, service, controller, etc. It's open source and is available for GKE, AWS/EKS, and other major providers. https://github.com/kubecost/cost-model